# Is it possible to insert missing sequence numbers in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, sequence

I am using Excel for this task now, but I was wondering if any of you know a way to find and insert missing sequence numbers in python.

Say I have a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Sequence':  [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10],
        'Value': ["x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x"]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['Sequence','Value'])
```

And now I want to use some code here to find missing sequence numbers in the column 'Sequence', and leave blank spaces at the column 'Values' for the rows of missing sequence numbers. To get the following output:

```
    print(df)

   Sequence Value
0         1     x
1         2     x
2         3     
3         4     x  
4         5     
5         6     x
6         7     x
7         8
8         9     x
9         10    x
```

Even better would be a solution in which you can also define the start and end of the sequence. For example when the sequence starts with 3 but you want it to start from 1 and end at 12. But a solution for only the first part will already help a lot. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3):

You can [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) using a range from the `Sequence`'s min and max values:

```
(df.set_index('Sequence')
   .reindex(range(df.Sequence.iat[0],df.Sequence.iat[-1]+1), fill_value='')
   .reset_index())

   Sequence Value
0         1     x
1         2     x
2         3      
3         4     x
4         5      
5         6     x
6         7     x
7         8      
8         9     x
9        10     x
```

Answer (score 2):

Or do it by merging DataFrames:

```
    seq = [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10]
    dfs0 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Sequence':  seq, 'Value': ['x']*len(seq)})
    dfseq = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Sequence': range( min(seq), max(seq)+1 )})
              .merge(dfs0, on='Sequence', how='outer').fillna('')
    print(dfseq)


   Sequence Value
0         1     x
1         2     x
2         3      
3         4     x
4         5      
5         6     x
6         7     x
7         8      
8         9     x
9        10     x
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```py
Sequence = [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1,12), columns=["Sequence"])
df = df.loc[df.Sequence.isin(Sequence), 'Value'] = 'x'
df = df.fillna('')
```

First you create your DataFrame with the given range of values you want it to have for sequence.
Then you set 'Value' to 'x' for the rows where 'Sequence' is in your Sequence list. Finally you fill the missing values with ''.